# React + Nodejs/Express App to display products

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, serial-port

I've got a simple React App with Nodejs/Express server.

Right now I'm trying to obtain an ID value from Serialport and compare that ID with the ID from an external webservice and retrieve the data I get from the webservice and display it on the frontend.

I've got the first part working and right now I can compare both ID's and fetch the data but can't figure out how to display it in the React frontend.

This is my server **index.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const scanProducts = () => {
    const scan = require('./actions/scanProduct');
    scan.scanner();
    //can't reach data here
}

app.listen(PORT);

scanProducts();
```

This is my **scanProduct.js**

```js
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');

module.exports = {
    scanner: function(){
        const port = new SerialPort({ path: 'COM6', baudRate: 9600, autoOpen: false });
        
        port.open(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message)
            }
            port.write('main screen turn on')
        })
        
        port.on('open', function() {
            setInterval(function(){
                const portReader = port.read();
                if(portReader != null){
        
                    const sensorVal = Buffer.from(portReader).toString();
               
                    const soap = require('soap');

                    const url = 'http://example.com?wsdl';
                    
                    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
                
                        client.GetProductById({ UserId: "1", ProductId: sensorVal }, function(err, result) {
                            if(err) return console.log(err);
                            console.log(result.GetProductByIdResult);
                            return result.GetProductByIdResult; //returns nothing into index.js
                        });
                    });
                    
                }
            }, 500);
        })
    }
}
```

Then I would like to add each product from the server into this custom component, right now it displays static data fetched from a basic json file.

This my component **ProductsList.js**:

```js
import ProductRow from "./ProductRow";

import './ProductsList.css';

const ProductsList = props => {

    
    return(
    <>
    <div id="products-wrapper" className="w-9/12 h-full px-20 py-20 flex flex-col overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll ">
        <div className="w-full h-auto my-2 px-3 py-3 font-semibold grid grid-cols-3 bg-blue-600 rounded-xl">
            <div className="w-[60%] text-left">Produto</div>
            <div className="w-[20%] text-left">Quant.</div>
            <div className="w-[20%] text-left">Preço</div>
        </div>
        
        {props.items.map(product => <ProductRow name={product.name} quantity={product.quantity} price={product.price}/>)}
        
        //here is where I need to add each product from the server
    </div>
  
    </>
    
    );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, to be sure, the workflow you want is : read serial port every 500ms -> retrieve some information  with it from a soap webservice -> send this to the react client and append the product list ? If the dataflow is controlled by your server, reading some serial port, working with websocket should be the easiest I think. When  you get some new product you send it to the client through the websocket. You can check [socketio](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks) library, which provides nice integration with react

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply @LoulouBadWeed, and thanks for the suggestion, I'll give socket.io a try. And that's indeed the workflow I'm trying to achieve, but first I need to get the result from my "scanProduct" file into my "index" file, when I "return result.GetProductByIdResult;", how can I store that value on a variable on my index.js file?

Comment: The port.on('open'), etc... are just listeners, they execute a function on some event and won't return anything. For a flexible approach you can look at [nodejs events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) . You can define an EventEmitter in your index.js file and pass this emitter as an argument to your scanner. 
Once a client is connected with a websocket, you can listen on some event, from the initial EventEmitter. On the scanner side, every 500ms after retrieving the data, you can emit an event with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample code for your project
I put some comments, I hope it will be easy to follow

I wrote some remarks at the end of the code too

***Backend***

For the **index.js** (main) file of your backend

```javascript
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var cors = require('cors')

// Init express app 
const app = require('express')();
// Import your scanner utility
const scan=require('./scanProduct')

/*Enabling CORS for any origin (host and port) to test the service from a another origin (react client) .
 It depends how you deploy your services */
app.use(cors({
    origin:'*'
}))
// Init the http server 
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
// Init the websocket library
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Define some plain emitter
const emitter=new EventEmitter()
// Pass the event emitter in it
scan.scanner(emitter)

// Event fired when the websocket has been established
io.on('connection', socket => {

    // When the scanProduct fire an event on scanner channel
    emitter.on("scanner",function(data){
        // Emit the data on the websocket for the react client
        // You can define whatever name you prefer, here also scanner
        socket.emit('scanner',data)
    })
 });

//Listening on port 8080
server.listen(8080);
```

And for the **scanProduct.js** file i just "mocked" your implementation with setInterval every 2 secs in my case

```javascript
module.exports = {
    scanner: function(eventEmitter){
        // Read serial port every 2000ms
        setInterval(()=>{
            /*  
            -  Read on serial port
            - fetch the data from the soap web service
            */

            // just some data to send but should be from your workflow
            const productResult=new Date().toISOString() 
            // you emit on the channel you defined in the index.js file
            eventEmitter.emit("scanner",productResult)  
        },2000)
    }
}
```

The depedencies I am using on the backend

```javascript
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.0"
  }
```

---

***Frontend***

For the front-end, I used npx create-react-app to init the project,
And I edited only one file, the ***App.js***  file

```javascript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// Websocket initialization, use your config or .env file to set up the url
const websocket = io(
  "http://localhost:8080",
  { transports: ['websocket'] }
)

function App() {
  //State keeping all the products we are displaying
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])


  //When App component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {

    // Just to log the connection
    websocket.on('connection', () => {
      console.log("Websocket connected")
    })
    // When websocket receive data on the scanner channel, emitted from the backend
    websocket.on("scanner", (product) => {
      // Update the products with new ones
      setProducts(prevProducts => [...prevProducts, product])
    })

  }, [])
  return (

    <div>
      <div>
        Number of products : {products.length}
      </div>
      {
        products.map((data) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {data}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My sample code as it is will send data every 2000ms and we will have en enormous list in no time ^^'.

For your use case, I do not know if it is relevant to send data every 500ms to the client.
Do you have continuous flow of valuable/usefull data on the serial port ? If you really have valuable data every 500ms, another approach would be more appropriate, like batching. The idea will be to save somewhere the products you collected every 500ms, and from titme to time, every 10 secondes for example, you send this list of new products to the client.

If the payload on the serial port arrives randomly, you need to build some logic into your setInterval function, and only trigger an event when necessary.

The sample of course lacks some features. You only have new products coming from the websocket, but no history. If you refresh your browser page or if the socket is closed for whatever reason, you are going to miss some products. If history is important, you need some persistence layer.

Comment: This solution is correct indeed, from you're sugestion of using socket.io I managed to get it all working, my solution is a bit diferent from yours but I got it all working, thanks a lot @LoulouBadWeed.

Comment: @RicardoCarneiro Great if it helped you ! all the best

Comment: Loulou my products are now being displayed correctly on my list, one product per row, but what I need is to display the first occurence of said product only once, and if any other occurence of the same product appear it only update the quantity, instead of adding a new row. I've figured I should use useContext for that but cant figure out how to make it work. Could you help me by any chance?

Comment: No need for a context I think. What you can try is, when you receive a new product from the websocket, iterate through your array, or whatever datatype you have in your state and check if an item with the same "name" is already there. If it exists, increment by one a counter on the object, if it is a new product, add a new entry. Find a data structure that is easy to use, where you can check the product "name" and have an occurrences field in it. The data structure can be a Map, an array of object, even an object. By  "name" I mean any kind of Id to identify properly your product